# Receiving input for a user, and storing the information in a vector

Tags: matlab

I need to create a matlab program that accepts numerical values from a user until they enter N, and store the values in a vector.

So far I have

```
Y=true;
N = false;
while (true)
    for k=...
        grades(k)=input('Enter a numerical value from 0 to 100: \n');
        d = input('Do you want to enter another grade? (Y/N): \n');
    end
end
```

The problem I am having is how do I store this information in a vector, if I don't know how many values the user is going to enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to concatenate the new user input to a user input vector. That way, your vector will always grow. The other thing is your `for` loop, you have to break the loop when the user types N, right? So you really don't need the two loops, or else your script will run indefinetly.

```
Y=true;
N = false;
grades = [];
while (d ~= 'n' && d ~= 'N')
    grades = [grades input('Enter a numerical value from 0 to 100: \n')];
    d = input('Do you want to enter another grade? (Y/N): \n');
end
```

One last thing: matlab will complain and suggest that you pre allocate the grades. But sine you don't know beforehand the size of the vector, and this is totally not about speed, this solution is good enough, I think.

Good luck